# please help me to resolve item problems

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I have many problems with items. Please help me:
[image]

As shown, the first item doesn't appear, the text is not formatted and after the items the paragraph doesn't begin from the begin.
Here is the code

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item A=\lbrace a_{ij}\rbrace: \textrm{the state transitions probability matrix as} \quad a_{ij}= P \left[ q_{t}=S_{j}\vert q_{t-1}=S_{i}\right]\quad \\ \textrm{with} \quad 1\leq i \leq N ; j\leq N; 0\leq a_{i}{j}\leq 1;\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}=1;\textrm{N denotes the model states number; t is the time;} q_{t} \textrm {shows the state of the model at t (a given instant) with} \quad 1 \leq t \leq T \quad \textrm{;T represents the observation sequence length; S denotes all the states set;}
   \item B=\lbrace b_{j}(k)\rbrace: \textrm{presents the observation \\symbols probability matrix with}\quad b_j(k)= P \left[O_{t}=V_{k} \vert q_{t}=S_{j}\right] \textrm{and}\quad 1\leq j \leq N ; 1 \leq k \leq M \textrm{;M is the various observation} \\\textrm{symbols number;} O_{t} \textrm{denotes the symbol of observation at (t) a given instant;}\\ V= \left \{ V_{1}\ .. \ V_{K}\right\} \textrm{shows all possible symbols of observation set;}
  \item \pi = \lbrace \pi_{i} \rbrace  \textrm{:denotes the initial state distribution with}       \pi_{i}= P \left[ q_{1}=S_{i}\right] \textrm{and}\quad 1 \leq i \leq N.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! We can help if we see your code.

Comment: I have added the code to the question.

Comment: The preamble would be useful too…

Comment: Are you by chance inside math mode when calling \begin{itemize} and the first \item? The lack of $ signs before your first formula suggests that ...

Comment: Your input is quite wrong, I'm afraid. You *must* enter math mode for formulas, not exiting from it for the text using `\textrm`. You get *many* error messages from TeX.

Comment: Yes, the context is missing…

Comment: Please help me with a simple example how to combine text and math mode. For example, if we want to write • A = {aij}: the state transitions probability matrix as aij= P[qt=Sj]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but nobody would use LaTeX if it forced such a horrible input code. Never disregard error messages you get when processing your input.

Math formulas should be segregated inside `$...$`, like in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$(A,B,\pi)$ having:
\begin{itemize}
\item $A=\{a_{ij}\}$: the state transitions probability
  matrix as $a_{ij}= P[ q_{t}=S_{j}\mid q_{t-1}=S_{i} ]$ with
  $1\leq i \leq N$; $j\leq N$; $0\leq a_{i}{j}\leq 1$; $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}=1$;
  $N$ denotes the model states number; $t$ is the time; $q_{t}$ shows the
  state of the model at $t$ (a given instant) with $1 \leq t \leq T$;
  $T$ represents the observation sequence length; $S$ denotes all the states set;

\item $B=\{b_{j}(k)\}$: presents the observation symbols probability
  matrix with $b_j(k)= P[O_{t}=V_{k} \mid q_{t}=S_{j}]$ and $1\leq j \leq N$;
  $1 \leq k \leq M$; $M$ is the various observation symbols number; $O_{t}$ denotes
  the symbol of observation at $t$ a given instant; $V=\{ V_{1}\dots V_{K}\}$
  shows all possible symbols of observation set;

\item $\pi = \{\pi_{i}\}$: denotes the initial state distribution with
  $\pi_{i}= P[q_{1}=S_{i}]$ and $1 \leq i \leq N$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\vert` in this context should be `\mid`; also the `\left` and `\right` instances you used are not necessary (and do harm, actually). Please, look closely at the code and fix your style.

[image]

Comment: +1. I would also replace the two instances of `\vert` with `\mid`. And, `a_{i}{j}` should probably be `a_{ij}`.

Comment: @Mico Done, plus something else